# why expression 'I_VALUE' cannot be used as an assignment target in Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsqldeveloper

I have created a function in oracle but it throws the error during the compilation.

```
 create or replace FUNCTION Get_Rounded_Value(i_Value NUMBER, i_Round_Type Varchar2, i_Round_Para NUMBER ) RETURN number
DETERMINISTIC
IS
v_Final_Value NUMBER(22,4);
BEGIN
v_Final_Value := 0;
i_Value := NVL(i_Value,0);
if i_Round_Type = 'D' then
v_Final_Value := Trunc(i_Value,i_Round_Para);
elsif i_Round_Type = 'U' then
v_Final_Value := Ceil(i_Value * Power(10, i_Round_Para)) / Power(10, i_Round_Para);
 ELSIF i_Round_Type = 'R' then
v_Final_Value := Round(i_Value, i_Round_Para);
ELSIF i_Round_Type = 'A' then 
v_Final_Value := Round(i_Value, i_Round_Para);
   if abs(v_final_value - i_value) < 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1)         then
      v_Final_Value := v_Final_Value + 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1);
     ELSIF abs(v_final_value - i_value) = 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) -     1) then
    v_Final_Value := v_Final_Value - 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1);
END IF;
 ELSIF i_Round_Type = 'B' then 
v_Final_Value := Ceil(i_Value * Power(10, i_Round_Para)) / Power(10,  i_Round_Para);
if abs(v_final_value - i_value) <= 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1) then
    v_Final_Value := v_Final_Value - 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1);
END IF;
  ELSIF i_Round_Type = 'C' then 
v_Final_Value := Trunc(i_Value,i_Round_Para);
if abs(v_final_value - i_Value) >= 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1) then
    v_Final_Value := v_Final_Value + 5 * power(10, (-1*i_Round_Para) - 1);
END IF;
 end if;
  Return NVL(v_Final_Value,0);
  END;
```

During the compile the Function I have get the following errors

Error(7,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(7,1): PLS-00363: expression 'I_VALUE' cannot be used as an assignment target

Answer (score 4):

Parameters are input unless otherwise specified as OUT or IN OUT.

It is bad practice to have a function which attempts to change the parameters passed to it. That is generally the purpose of a procedure.

An IN OUT or OUT parameter can't haves constants / literals passed to it. They must, by definition, be variables.